# Installing Tomcat in ubuntu

Tags: server, permissions, java, tomcat

I have download apache-tomcat-x.x.x.tar.gz from apache . I have extracted it and set the CATALINA_HOME. Have given permission to all the sh file to bin. While running catalina.sh jpda start, then I am getting following error.

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/sitakanta/server/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/sitakanta/server/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/sitakanta/server/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/jdk1.7.0_71
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/sitakanta/server/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/bin/bootstrap.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /home/sitakanta/server/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/tomcat.pid
Usage: catalina.sh ( commands ... )
commands:
  debug             Start Catalina in a debugger
  debug -security   Debug Catalina with a security manager
  jpda start        Start Catalina under JPDA debugger
  run               Start Catalina in the current window
  run -security     Start in the current window with security manager
  start             Start Catalina in a separate window
  start -security   Start in a separate window with security manager
  stop              Stop Catalina, waiting up to 5 seconds for the process to end
  stop n            Stop Catalina, waiting up to n seconds for the process to end
  stop -force       Stop Catalina, wait up to 5 seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running
  stop n -force     Stop Catalina, wait up to n seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running
  version           What version of tomcat are you running?
Note: Waiting for the process to end and use of the -force option require that $CATALINA_PID is defined
```

Comment: Why don't you use the one from the repository?  If you want to run it as a server, just install `tomcat7` and if you want to have different user installations for developing, install `tomcat7-user`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the packages from the repository.

Use and install `tomcat7` and you get one server up and running.  You might also want to check that package `tomcat7-admin`, `tomcat7-examples` and `tomcat7-doc` are installed.

If you just want to develop and run a couple of Tomcat7 servers, just install package `tomcat7-user`, `tomcat7-examples` and `tomcat7-doc` and you then can create many different Tomcat 7 servers with the command `tomcat7-instance-create`.  Look into `/usr/share/doc/tomcat7*` for documenation and the `man` pager for the command `tomcat7-instance-create`.